# Netflix lags on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire, netflix, fios

I just got an Acer Aspire 5250 and have been trying to run Netflix on it with little or no success. The laptop has Windows 7 as the OS and Verizon Fios as the ISP. The picture is fine is just that it after I start playing a movie/show, the audio lags behind the video. Any suggestions of what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Does it do it with just a few? or All?

Comment: With all videos it does this.

Comment: Check the speedtests, make sure it's not too slow. Also, try a different browser.

Comment: Thanks. Did a speed test. Did it twice and the best results I got were 8.49 Mb/s download and 3.73 upload. D/l Opera only to find out that it won't even run Netflix and then d/l Firefox and that kept skipping and was worse than the current Chrome browser I have.

Comment: Slightly odd. Might be worth stopping all programs from running before watching Netflix. Silverlight isn't CPU friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It may just be the laptop isn't powerful enough. Netflix works like a charm on my desktop with no issues at all.

Comment: What happens if you play a DVD vs trying to stream?  What about a local video file?

Comment: Playing a DVD works smoothly. A LVF works perfectly fine too.

Comment: Been mainly using Netflix through Roku and my desktop. If I ever watch it on my laptop and it lags, I scroll through it slightly and it's fine the rest of the way. Annoying, yes, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [spec's](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2011/Acer/Aspire/Aspire5250/Aspire5250sp2.shtml) you have an AMD Radeon graphics card. You should ensure that this has the most update to date software. If that is the case you should look for a beta release as sometimes they will have experimental patches that may solve your issues.

Comment: I d/l the AMD Vision Engine Control Center and played around with it. It seems to have helped somewhat. Will continue fiddling with it. Thanks for you help.